# unable to start application

Tags: appium-android, katalon-studio

[java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create a new remote session. Please check the server log for more details. Original error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Error executing adbExec. Original error: 'Command 'C:\Users\HP\.katalon\tools\android_sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s 4e34017d shell 'settings delete global hidden_api_policy_pre_p_apps;settings delete global hidden_api_policy_p_apps;settings delete global hidden_api_policy'' exited with code 255'; Command output:
Exception occurred while executing 'delete':
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denial: writing to settings requires:android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS
at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.enforceWritePermission(SettingsProvider.java:2374)
at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.mutateGlobalSetting(SettingsProvider.java:1413)
at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.mutateGlobalSetting(SettingsProvider.java:1405)
at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.deleteGlobalSetting(SettingsProvider.java:1376)]

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjM73.png)